# How to export db file from SQLLite

Tags: export, csv

I have uploaded my csv file to https://sqliteonline.com/ and it is currently available as a table. I need to export this data to .db file to use it elsewhere. I tried exporting the table, but I only have choices to export as jason, sql, etc, and not db.

I tried running the command

```
  create database test;
```

to try to move the table under it and export but create database test; generated errors.
Could you please help me export this as a db file? Alternatively, if you recommend other tools that can get this done that would be great too.

Comment: That's just a free 3rd party website someone made to allow you to interact with databases online (akin to [dbfiddle.uk](https://dbfiddle.uk)) for playing around and testing. I don't think anyone here can offer much advice on how to use it other than you shouldn't use it for actual work you want to save - rather you should use a real database instance, such as running SQLite locally. Regardless, it does look like under *File* there's a *Save DB* option which downloads a DB file.

Comment: @J.D. thanks for your feedback. I am working on a research project with limited budget. Do all local database programs have the option to export .db file?

Comment: "*I am working on a research project with limited budget.*" - SQLite is free. So is SQL Server Express Edition if you want a centralized server. "*Do all local database programs have the option to export .db file?*" - When not running them in the cloud, sure, you should have access to the DB files. SQLite is generally a single DB file on your local device that you can copy and move as needed. Not sure what your goal is with exporting it though.

Comment: @J.D. thanks, would you like to share your answer so that I can accept it?

Comment: Sure, answer Posted. Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> I have uploaded my csv file to https://sqliteonline.com/ and it is currently available as a table. I need to export this data to .db file to use it elsewhere.

That's just a free 3rd party website someone made to allow you to interact with databases online (akin to [dbfiddle.uk](https://dbfiddle.uk/)) for playing around and testing. You should use a real database instance, such as running SQLite locally. Regardless, it does look like under *File* there's a *Save DB* option which downloads a DB file.

> I am working on a research project with limited budget.

SQLite is free. So is SQL Server Express Edition if you want a centralized server.

> Do all local database programs have the option to export .db file?

When not running them in the cloud, sure, you should have access to the DB files. SQLite is generally a single DB file on your local device that you can copy and move as needed.